# Python: How to Handle a .CSV with Dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, import

I have a .csv file with several thousands data points in the form:

```
Timestamp                  Variable
2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  3.6
```

I would like to import the data and create a 2D array with the timestamps in the first column and the variable values in the second. What's the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `pandas` is the library you need to manage your kind of data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv') 

res = df.values
```

You will need to look the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) on `pandas` to complete `read_csv` with the corrects arguments

Comment: I'll try pandas then.

Answer (score 0):

For the community's benefit, here is the instruction that solves my problem using pandas library. In my file, there are `X` and `Y` rows of metadata to skip respectively before and after the data of interest; your mileage may vary.

```
import pandas as pds
Y_raw= pds.read_csv('mydata.csv',
                  delimiter=',', header = None, engine = 'python',
                  skiprows = X, skipfooter = Y,
                  usecols = [0,1], names = ["TimeStamp", "Var"],  
                  parse_dates = [0], infer_datetime_format = True) ]
```

Then I can extract the `Var` and `TimeStamp` arrays with:

```
Y = Y_raw.iloc[:,1]
Z = y_raw.iloc[:,0]
```